How can I get the AI button to show up in Figma?
I would like to try Figma's recently released AI features, but the AI button does not show up in the UI. I'm surprised this info seems nowhere to be found, when the AI feature is so much advertised and many videos are showing up on YouTube, but their interface does not match mine.
What I see

What I need

Notice the magic blue button on the right side of the toolbar

Are you a part of a team that has an Admin account? It "might" be disabled by your admin. Are you using Figma or Figma Beta?

Thanks @AndrewH. I have the default team that was created automatically. AI features are on for the team. I just tried Figma Beta also and experiencing the same issue.

Any update on that? I am also facing the same issue.

I'm voting to close because this is a question for Figma support, not a graphic design issue.

Just gotta wait for it.
One fine day you will see a popup like this. This means have access to the beta UI enhancements (as currently they are rolling it out in phases).


Once you have that, then you gotta wait for it again.
As with the recent issue that Figma faced with the design systems that the AI used. They have paused the access to Figma AI for now.

Once its live, everyone on Beta will have access to it.

